# Specific float structure of divs between a div

Tags: css

Is it possible to float divs between a div in this way?

[image]

The code:

```
<div class="event_month">
<div class="event1">1</div>
<div class="event2">2</div>
<div class="event3">3</div>
<div class="event4">4</div>
<div class="event5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser do you have to support?

Comment: is the order of the divs important?

Comment: i have to support the Internet Explorer from Version 10, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome. Yes, the order is important ;-)

Comment: You can't do that simply with floats. You could do it with absolute positioning but that would be horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/C6fwj/3/) would be a css solution for modern browsers:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    width: 210px;
    background: chocolate;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px;
    list-style: none;
    column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-width: 100px;
    -moz-column-width: 100px;
    -webkit-column-width: 100px;
    column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    font-size: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    background: beige;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

Note: I think IE10 understands CSS columns.

Update: [Here's the same with divs](http://jsfiddle.net/C6fwj/1/), just for proof...

Update 2: Chrome (webkit) doesn't work correctly if you just float the wrapper, must set a width for that, if you want the wrapper to fit.

Comment: Seems to be a bit buggy in webkit though, I'm working on a proper one.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
    HTML:
<div class="event_month outer_styling">
  <div class="float-left">
    <div class="event1">1</div>
    <div class="event2">2</div>
    <div class="event3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="float-left">
    <div class="event4">4</div>
    <div class="event5">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.float-left {
    float: left;
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/SSxWz/2/